# jquery .parent() usage

Tags: jquery, parent, siblings

Here is my code :

```
<div id="reason_bars">Reason <select style="width:200px;" disabled="disabled"><option><option></select>
<div class="edit" style="position:absolute;left:212px;top:50px;">Edit</div></div>
```

i want to trigger an event, where , if one clicks on the div with class="edit" , the  element(its sibling) gets enabled,

i tried the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#reason_bars .edit").click(function () {
var parent=$(this).parent();
$(parent+" select").removeAttr("disabled");
});
});
```

this doesn't work.

Is there any alternative ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#reason_bars .edit").click(function () {
          $(this).siblings('select').removeAttr("disabled");
     )}
});
```

In your line `$(parent+" select")` parent is a reference to an object, not a string which is why it doesnt work. You also can use the jQuery sibling selector to simplify things.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write this as `$(parent).find('select').removeAttr("disabled")`

Answer (score 1):

try ths:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".edit").click(function () {
   $(this).parent().find('select').removeAttr("disabled");
  });
 });
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/GMTfK/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#reason_bars .edit").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find("select").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```